# Excel VBA Sub ends after .save

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large number of company worksheets that need to have a formula patched. I created a subroutine to do this, but each time in the loop when it saves a worksheet it opened, it ends the sub.
I tested the code with no save, and it works as expected that way. It's just that any save event (I tried a couple) ends the sub. What am I missing?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    Sub OpenAndReplace()  ''When run, it should go through selected PF worksheets , change a formula, save, close, go to next worksheet.

Dim PFList, PFListCurrFile As Variant   ''List of PF worksheets and current worksheet respectively
Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbkCurBook, wbkPF As Workbook

Set wbkCurBook = ThisWorkbook  '' Current workbook with this macros.

'' Select files to be corercted
PFList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose files to correct", MultiSelect:=True)

If (vbBoolean = VarType(PFList)) Then End   '' If null then end. No files were selected
If (UBound(PFList) = 0) Then End '' if greater then 0 count in array then continue

countFiles = 0  '' File counter. Set to 0, incremented below when valid file is opened

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


For Each PFListCurrFile In PFList   '' for each file in the list. START OF LOOP ### Loop per workbook

    Application.EnableEvents = False  '' Turn macros off for opening of document
    Set wbkPF = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=PFListCurrFile, ReadOnly:=False)    ''Open it up and set it as Workbook object
    Application.EnableEvents = True   '' Turn macros back on
    countFiles = countFiles + 1  '' increment the counter


With wbkPF.Sheets("Page1")
    
    Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=Data!R[-49]C[6]/1000"

End With ''***

''Close and save method#1
''wbkPF.Close SaveChanges:=True 

''Close and save method#2
wbkPF.Save                    
wbkPF.Close SaveChanges:=False 

Next         '' For Each PFListCurrFile In PFList. END OF LOOP ###  Loop per workbook

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: You need a `.` in front of `Range("F1").FormulaR1C1`

Comment: You have some coding assumptions that are incorrect.  Please install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and then take a look at the code inspections.

Comment: Thanks, BigBen. I accidentally lopped it of trying to clean it up for posting.

Comment: Do the workbooks have any macros that run on or before closing ?

Comment: Brilliant! That was it. Turns out there was a OnSave sub on the documents. I delayed the <pre><code>Application.EnableEvents = True</code></pre>until after the save and it works. A million thanks!!!